# Flex inside flex with overflow-x

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create 2 columns inline. The first column has fixed width of 200px and second column should take up the rest of the screen. The second column should autoscroll on the x-axis. I've been trying to use flex but I'm very confused by the markup. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Path: `html`

```
<section className="container">
  <div className="container-name">1</div>
  <div className="container-time">
    <div className="element">
      222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222999999
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Path:  `CSS`

```
.container {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.container-name {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.container-time {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired output using:

- `max-width` on the `container`
- `display: inline-flex;` on the `container`
- `max-width` on the `container-time`

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container-name {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container-time {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="container-name">1</div>
  <div class="container-time">
    <div class="element">
      222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will help you!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container .split {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .split__left {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.container .split__right {
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container .split__right p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="split split__left"></div>
  <div class="split split__right">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil repellat sapiente assumenda. Ex fugit at amet sed libero eaque. Debitis obcaecati aperiam hic possimus unde. Voluptatibus cumque illo dolores architecto.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil repellat sapiente assumenda. Ex fugit at amet sed libero eaque. Debitis obcaecati aperiam hic possimus unde. Voluptatibus cumque illo dolores architecto.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil repellat sapiente assumenda. Ex fugit at amet sed libero eaque. Debitis obcaecati aperiam hic possimus unde. Voluptatibus cumque illo dolores architecto.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil repellat sapiente assumenda. Ex fugit at amet sed libero eaque. Debitis obcaecati aperiam hic possimus unde. Voluptatibus cumque illo dolores architecto.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil repellat sapiente assumenda. Ex fugit at amet sed libero eaque. Debitis obcaecati aperiam hic possimus unde. Voluptatibus cumque illo dolores architecto.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[NOTE]** see this in bigger screen.